# How to get the content of an answer?

Tags: java, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to build a data set based on Stackoverflow question and answers for testing some Natural Language Processing algorithms. So far, I have a small Java program that based on a set of keywords it retrieves questions from StackOverflow tagged with these keywords.

In the next step, I need to retrieve the actual content of the question. In other words, given a question Id, how can I retrieve its content (content==the actual text written by the user)?

Is it possible to do this with the StackOverflow API?

If not, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example URL for getting the content of your question:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/16640957?body=true

The content is in the `body` field. [More info](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids).

Answer (score 2):

[image]from http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids

```
body: When "true", a post's body will be included in the response.
```

It's what your looking for. ;)